# why and when override public function set data

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I had make some research over the internet about the itemRender i just found some articles that describe the itemRender like [Adobe Item Render](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html) , [The Best Practice with item render in flex development](http://www.nixsolutions.com/blog/development/flash/the-best-practices-with-itemrenderer-in-flex-development/) all these articles explain how ItemRender works? But they did not specified why we are overriding the set data method? Why we are calling `super.data = value`? Hope you will help me.

```
 <s:itemRenderer>
 <fx:Component>                 
 <s:ItemRenderer autoDrawBackground="false" width="100%" height="100%" >                        
 <fx:Script>                     
    override public function set data(value:Object):void
    {
        super.data = value; }

                        ]]>

               </fx:Script>                     
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that overriding the set data method isn't always necessary.  You can use the binding syntax and rely on the default ItemRenderer's set data function, e.g.

```
<s:Label text="{data.labelText}" />
```

That being said, overriding set data allows you to trigger more complex behaviors when a new element is being displayed.  One possible use for this is a scrolling list where each entry glows for about half a second when it first comes into view.

Calling `super.data = value;` in your override function simply invokes the default behavior, in this case setting `ItemRenderer's` underlying `data` property  It's standard practice to do this in an override unless you're actively trying to avoid doing something that the parent class does.